# Build a PyObject* from a C function?

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I am embedding Python in a C++ library which I am making. I would like users to be able to pass C functions in the form of function pointers `PyObject* (fpFunc*)(PyObject*,PyObject*);` so that I can use those functions in the embedded Python.

So I have a function pointer and I know that it is possible to put this function as a module's method using a `PyMethodDef` struct and passing it to `Py_InitModule("module", ModMethods);` and thus obtaining a `PyObject* module` which I can easily grab functions from.

But, what I would really appreciate is to be able to create this function on the fly without necessarily recreating another module each time.

I have looked into the Python docs, and some of the Python headers to think about a hacky way of doing this without real success... but I'm wondering if's there's a more conventional way of doing this.

From what I understood, every function belongs to a module, even `__builtin__`, so I guess I would require at least on module.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. Why are you using a function pointer? Who's setting it?

Comment: I'm making a C++ library which embeds Python. I'm using a function pointer because it's handy to pass around. (edited my post)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Found it. Though it's not in the docs and it's hardly explicit in the source.

```
PyObject* (*fpFunc)(PyObject*,PyObject*) = someFunction;
PyMethodDef methd = {"methd",fpFunc,METH_VARARGS,"A new function"};
PyObject* name = PyString_FromString(methd.ml_name);
PyObject* pyfoo = PyCFunction_NewEx(&methd,NULL,name);
Py_DECREF(name);
```

It works. I can call the function like I normally would call a Python function object.

If you're curious, all I found in the doc was about `Py_InitModule4` and loading modules, so I went to check Python's source, and found out about `PyCFunction`, then I looked around in the doc but I couldn't find anything about `PyCFunction_NewEx`, so I had to check the source to make sure it was as I thought.

Comment: Thanks, not sure though you really need `name` as `PyCFunction_New` macro just calls `PyCFunction_NewEx` with `NULL` as third parameter